# Custom Event Dynamic Action based on $(document) jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, dom, oracle-apex

I've been using dynamic actions based on custom events in one of my Oracle Apex pages. I am binding my event to the document and then using a 'DOM Object' selection type (of document) in order to specify the context for the event.

[image]
This works in Apex 4.2, however I have just come across this in relation to Apex 5:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39143/toc.htm#BAJDAGJG

> 5.10 Deprecation of Dynamic Actions Based on DOM Objects
>
> Dynamic actions based on DOM Objects have been deprecated. Change your
>   dynamic actions to use a jQuery Selector or JavaScript Expression
>   instead of DOM Object.

My question is, how can I use a jQuery selector in order to detect events bound to the document? When I try using a jQuery selector of `document`, the dynamic action does not fire. I strongly suspect that this is because APEX wraps the selector in quotes when the dynamic action is parsed, rendering it useless for selectors on the document or window objects.

I am already aware that in the standard jQuery world I would just use `$(document)`.

[image]

I already know that I can bind events to different DOM elements. I'm not interested in that. I am interested specifically in binding to document.

Comment: I haven't tried much with Apex 5 yet, but have you tried `:root` as your jQuery selector? Not exactly the same as document, but might give you the same behaviour.

Comment: I have tried `:root` as my selector, with the event being bound to `document`. It didn't work. So from that I assume that the event does not bubble up from the document?

Comment: My suggestion wasn't well thought out. Events bubble from child elements up as far as the root element, but that doesn't help you since your event not bound to an element, but to the document node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery selectors return element nodes. Your event is bound to the document node, so there's no way to get at it with a jQuery selector. `$(document)` is not strictly speaking a selector. I believe `$(":root").parent()` returns the `document` object but that doesn't help you, since Oracle only lets you use selectors, not methods.

Oracle got back to me earlier with my Apex 5 workspace, so I've been having a play. The solution is in the documentation you quoted. You can't use a jQuery selector in your dynamic action's Selection Type, but you can simply use a Javascript Expression, with the value: `document`

I tested this by creating a button pointing to the URL:

```
javascript:apex.event.trigger(document,'testEvent');
```

I created a dynamic action responding to the Custom Event `testEvent`, Selection Type `Javascript Expression`, expression value `document`. It works fine, and the button now triggers an alert via a custom event handled at the document.

Comment: Thanks for this. Interesting. I am using Oracle Apex 4.2 and JavaScript Expression is not a selection type option. I have already implemented this another way (attaching the event to an element that I can use a jQuery selector with), but just wanted to play Devil's Advocate as I thought it might be a bad idea to deprecate a feature whilst no complete alternative exists in historical versions.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Example**: How a dynamic action custom event placed ( **oracle apex 18.1** ) to **refresh interactive report** section :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice example but irrelevant to question.